Problems with the update in CRUD PHP Codeigniter 4
I'm trying to do a CRUD with Codeigniter 4, it's my first time using this framework. I created the Database in Mysql and I have already done the register and login ( they work at the moment) So on the landing page, I created a button to edit the user data. But it doesn't work.... only shows me the last error which means that the save function isn't working properly. Someone can help me? I'm super lost at this moment!
This is my edit controller
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\UserModel;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Edit extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        if (!$this->session->has('user_id')) {
            return redirect()->to('/login');
        }

        $user = session()->get('user_data');

        if ($user === null) {
            return redirect()->to('/landing')->with('error', 'No se pudieron obtener los datos del usuario.');
        }

        return view('edit', ['user' => $user]);
    }

    public function save()
    {
        if (!$this->session->has('user_id')) {
            return redirect()->to('/login');
        }

        if ($this->request->getMethod() === 'post') {
            $userData = [
                'name' => $this->request->getPost('name'),
                'email' => $this->request->getPost('email'),
                // Puedes agregar el campo password si es necesario, pero ten en cuenta que no es seguro almacenar contraseñas en texto plano.
                // 'password' => $this->request->getPost('password'),
            ];

            if (empty($userData['name']) || empty($userData['email'])) {
                return redirect()->to('/edit')->with('error', 'Por favor, complete todos los campos.');
            }

            $userModel = new UserModel();
            $updateStatus = $userModel->update(session()->get('user_id'), $userData);

            echo $userData;

            if ($updateStatus) {
                session()->set('user_data', $userData);
                return redirect()->to('/edit')->with('success', 'Perfil actualizado con éxito');
            } else {
                return redirect()->to('/home')->with('error', 'No se pudo actualizar el perfil.');
            }
        }

        return redirect()->to('/edit')->with('error', 'Método de solicitud no permitido.');
    }
}


This is my view
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Editar Perfil</title>
    <link href="<?= base_url('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h1 class="text-center">Editar Perfil</h1>

        <!-- Mensajes de éxito o error -->
        <?php if (session()->getFlashdata('success')) : ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <?= session()->getFlashdata('success') ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if (session()->getFlashdata('error')) : ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <?= session()->getFlashdata('error') ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if (isset($user) && $user !== null) : ?>
            <form action="<?= base_url('edit-users') ?>" method="post">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="name" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="<?= esc($user['name']) ?>" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="email" class="form-label">Correo Electrónico</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<?= esc($user['email']) ?>" required>
                </div>
                <!-- Si necesitas manejar contraseñas, añade el campo de contraseña, pero ten en cuenta la seguridad -->
                <!-- <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="password" class="form-label">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
                </div> -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>
            </form>
        <?php else : ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                No se pudieron cargar los datos del usuario.
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <a href="<?= base_url('landing') ?>" class="btn btn-secondary mt-3">Cancelar</a>
    </div>
    <script src="<?= base_url('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') ?>"></script>
</body>

</html>

And this is my model that works with the register
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = ['name', 'email', 'password'];


    protected $beforeInsert = ['hashPassword'];
    protected $beforeUpdate = ['hashPassword'];


    protected function hashPassword(array $data)
    {
        if (isset($data['data']['password'])) {
            $data['data']['password'] = password_hash($data['data']['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Método para obtener un usuario por su correo electrónico.
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return array|null
     */


    public function getUserByEmail($email)
    {
        return $this->where('email', $email)->first();
    }

    /**
     * Método para guardar un nuevo usuario en la base de datos.
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return int|false ID del usuario insertado o false si falla
     */



    public function saveUser($data)
    {
        try {
            return $this->insert($data);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            if ($this->db->error()['code'] == 1062) {
                return false;
            } else {
                throw $e;
            }
        }
    }

    public function updateUser($id, $data)
    {
        return $this->where('id', $id)->set($data)->update();
    }
}


And my routes
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');

$routes->get('/register', 'Register::index');
$routes->post('/register-users', 'Register::save');


$routes->get('/login', 'Login::index');
$routes->post('/login-users', 'Login::process');

$routes->get('/edit', 'Edit::index');
$routes->post('/edit-users', 'Edit::save');

$routes->get('/landing', 'Landing::index');
$routes->post('/logout', 'Landing::logout');

It's difficult to catch the error with tthe console in php

There is an echo after $updateStatus declaration. Not sure if that would prevent the correct encoding of the redirection

As an aside, if (isset($user) && $user !== null) doesn't make sense if you know what isset() does.

I tried using the echo to see what it returned, but I removed it, and it still doesn't work.
And I didn't know what isset(), it's my first time using Codeigniter. I have replaced it to if (isset($user)) :

This is the actual error
_ci_last_regenerate|i:1721471637;_ci_previous_url|s:61:"http://localhost/formulario/version2/myproject/index.php/edit";user_id|s:2:"36";user_data|a:6:{s:2:"id";s:2:"36";s:4:"name";s:6:"Alvaro";s:5:"email";s:16:"alvaro@gmail.com";s:8:"password";s:60:"$2y$10$w0W8h/olPk8ZH9XKZMA6c.ZV1fnxcwptZIV2/rzzaSV6UeYUe3F.O";s:5:"cover";N;s:4:"role";s:7:"Usuario";}error|s:34:"Método de solicitud no permitido.";__ci_vars|a:1:{s:5:"error";s:3:"old";}
I don't know if it is related to CSRF

Take care when you post log information that contains data. Change your  gmail password now. And it is not related to CSRF. Read the error message therein. It pays to look closely.

For the problem trouble-shooting this: If you can't get a step-debugger running (xdebug), error_log() is not as comfortable but it does not interfere with the output and uses the PHP SAPI error/logging channel. That is compatible with every PHP SAPI and documented in the PHP manual. Most frameworks also offer their own logging, but that is not as universally accessible. At the end of the day you'd like to master all those three things: Step debugging, PHP SAPI error logging, and the frameworks logging. We find error_log() very useful for starters. https://php.net/function.error-log .

@hakre thank you very much for all this useful information. I am just a beginner and my knowledge is low. The gmail is fake, just to test that it registers and logs into the database. I will carefully read the manual you sent me.

You're welcome, good to read & take care.

Could you post the error that gets logged in /writable/logs/log-DATE.log when trying to save/update the user?

Hi Simon! I have no errors saved there. I only have it in the session folder

Is CSRF enaled? If so, then try to add CSRF token as a hidden input field, for example after your form html element insert this: <?= csrf_field() ?>
Alternatively you can use form_open/form_close helper functions (you have to enable it before you use these functions)
Alternatively you can disable CSRF filter in the Config\Filters::$globals property (NOT recommended way)
